# OpenForm and OpenQuery macro buttons on unbound Access form makes it slow to load?

Tags: forms, performance, ms-access, button, navigation

Do unbound Access forms become slow to load, save, and switch back and forth to design mode when they have too many buttons?

I have added 2 buttons for opening forms, and 9 buttons for opening queries in read only datasheet mode, using the wizard to create the macros.

I tried it once starting with a blank form, and then again using the navigation form wizard to create the form, from which I then removed the tabs and layout. The buttons are in the Details section of the form.

Either way, it's like I set a battleship on my form. It's a pig. My other forms fly (still) even though they really are loaded down.  Is Access (2016) compiling these queries or something, just because they're referenced by the buttons/macros? The database is about 16Mb (non-split on my desktop) and hasn't been slow otherwise. Advice?

Thank you.

-Tony.

Comment: Do you execute any code when loading the form, AND/OR do you have any queries that execute on load (i.e. listbox or combobox, etc.)?

Comment: Never mind. I just used the Designer "Convert form's macros to Visual Basic" function and now everything is perfect. Opens in less than a second, as opposed to the 120 secs or more it took before. Is this typical of macros?

Comment: It would be helpful to others in the future if you explain what the issue was and how it was solved. The original question asked about buttons - which involve zero overhead unless clicked - thus the reason for asking if code / queries were being executed at load time.

Comment: There was no code behind, only the macros for opening the forms and queries. There weren't even any parameters. I had checked that each worked, and they did just fine. I compacted and repaired and it was no help. It seems the fact they were macros was the issue. Converting to VBA made the issue go away. That's all I know. Seems weird to me too.